# Remove name, dtype from pandas output of dataframe or series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, output-formatting

I have output file like this from a pandas function.

```
Series([], name: column, dtype: object)
311     race
317     gender
Name: column, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to get an output with just the second column, i.e.,

```
race
gender
```

by deleting top and bottom rows, first column. How do I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want just the `.values` attribute:

```
In [159]:

s = pd.Series(['race','gender'],index=[311,317])
s
Out[159]:
311      race
317    gender
dtype: object
In [162]:

s.values
Out[162]:
array(['race', 'gender'], dtype=object)
```

You can convert to a list or access each value:

```
In [163]:

list(s)
Out[163]:
['race', 'gender']

In [164]:

for val in s:
    print(val)
race
gender
```

Comment: This is a hack compared to the `to_string` answer.

Comment: This is a hack compared to [`to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html), which allows much more fine-grained control of name, index, header, also length, dtype, float_format and na_rep, max_rows and min_rows.

Answer (score 50):

### [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)/[`Series.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html)

These methods have a variety of arguments that allow you configure what, and how, information is displayed when you print. By default `Series.to_string` has `name=False` and `dtype=False`, so we additionally specify `index=False`:

```
s = pd.Series(['race', 'gender'], index=[311, 317])

print(s.to_string(index=False))
#   race
# gender
```

---

If the Index is important the default is `index=True`:

```
print(s.to_string())
#311      race
#317    gender
```

---

### [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

When you don't care about the index and just want the values left justified cat with a `'\n'`. Values need to be strings, so convert first if necessary.

```
#s = s.astype(str)

print(s.str.cat(sep='\n'))
#race
#gender
```

Comment: I like how this is explicit, but it left whitespace at the beginning of my string. In my case I can remove it with `strip()` but if there is a possibility that your dataframe element actually starts with whitespace, that could be dangerous.

Comment: @craq Good point. The default left-justification of the index and right-justification of values makes it very difficult to get the proper justification with the `to_string` methods if you don't need the index Instead `Series.str.cat` is the best solution as it will preserve initial white-space, if any

Comment: I suggest you add that `to_string()` allows much more fine-grained control of name, index, header, also length, dtype, float_format and na_rep, max_rows and min_rows. –

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes I do `print(*s, sep='\n')`:

```
s = pd.Series(['race', 'gender'], index=[311, 317])
print(*s, sep='\n')
```

gives

```
race
gender
```