# Printing pandas df without column name

Tags: python, pandas, database

I've been trying to open a .csv, read it in pandas, and print it without the column name. The code I have

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='C:/Users/R2/Documents/Desktop/Programing/Bot/list.csv')
rows = df.loc[[i]]
values = rows.to_string(index = False)
print(values)
```

Outputs something like this

```
Value  
 12343
```

How would I make it so values equal only 12343 and not Value  12343

Comment: `rows` is a DataFrame, print the `Series`, which won't have a column header. `rows = df.loc[i]`. And depending upon left or right justification you can use the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645153/remove-name-dtype-from-pandas-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
values = rows.to_string(index = False, header=False)
print(values)
```