# python pandas: removing name and dtype in iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

i'm currently working on an inventory systsem.
How do i remove "Name:,dtype:" in the iterows?
Or is there other way that I can show the row's info ?
Thanks

````
1 Name                  cat
Unit Price          $2.00
Quantity                2
Price               $4.00
Expiry Date    0002-02-02
Expired?               No
Name: 1, dtype: object
2 Name                    2
Unit Price          $2.00
Quantity                2
Price               $4.00
Expiry Date    2003-02-02
Expired?               No
Name: 2, dtype: object
3 Name                  dog
Unit Price          $2.00
Quantity                2
Price               $4.00
Expiry Date    0002-02-02
Expired?               No
Name: 3, dtype: object
4 Name                mouse
Unit Price          $3.00
Quantity                3
Price               $9.00
Expiry Date    0003-03-03
Expired?               No
Name: 4, dtype: object
5 Name                    3
Unit Price          $3.00
Quantity                3
Price               $9.00
Expiry Date    0003-03-03
Expired?               No
Name: 5, dtype: object```
````

Comment: You have a list of `Series`?

Comment: I think this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645153/remove-name-dtype-from-pandas-output-of-dataframe-or-series) answers your question!

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you're just printing data then why should it matter since this only appears when you print

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove name, dtype from pandas output of dataframe or series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645153/remove-name-dtype-from-pandas-output-of-dataframe-or-series)

Comment: You do not give the initial dataframe, nor the code you have used to obtain (and print)  that sequence of Series, and to not even show the expected output... How can we help you :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`Series.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html) method before printing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(3,4)))

for name,s in df.iterrows():
    print(f'row: {name}')
    print(s.to_string())  # to_string outputs only the data, not the metadata
```

example:

```
row: 0
0    9
1    0
2    9
3    5
row: 1
0    1
1    2
2    5
3    6
row: 2
0    0
1    1
2    5
3    5
```